# Age calculation Query - optimization return time

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is mean to:

- Filter peoples incorrect date so that it only calculates people that have the correct date "DAY-MONTH-YEAR" (02-Dec-1986)
- Calculate their age between 2 parameters.

I don't know if 1.029 SECs is normal for this type of query or I am doing something wrong that make is a bit slow. Could anyone advice me if I've done something that could be optimized?

as it stands my query takes `( 870,968 total, Query took 1.0297 sec)`
and the actual query is

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age  
FROM impressions AS i, mariners AS m  
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL 
  AND m_dob != '' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 BETWEEN 13 AND 50 
ORDER BY `age`  DESC
```

Comment: Please post your table structures. Do you realize that you are getting a cartesian result between those tables?  You are not actually joining them.  Do you need the `impressions` table? It does not look like you are using that table.

Comment: If i dont put impression table i get less results `( 28 total, Query took 0.0051 sec)` What do you mean by cartesian results?. I have 97 colums there and no index. you want the 97 colums in detail?.

Comment: A Cartesian result takes every row from each table to join, so if each table has 4 rows, your result will have 16 rows. See [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join). Do you need both tables to get your result? Do the tables have a column that will allow for joining?

Comment: Yes, I need both tables. I find it weird that it return less results without impression when Impression table doesnt hold DoB. yes i have a colum that would enable me to join them. I would join them `i.SessionID = m.ID ` in a similar query  i need to get the people that have impression =1

Comment: You get less results without the `impressions` table because in your original query you are combining each row from the first table with each row of the each table.  You are multiplying the results.

Comment: if i try `SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age  FROM  mariners AS m INNER JOIN impressions AS i on i.SessionID = m.ID  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL AND m_dob != '' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 BETWEEN 13 AND 50 ORDER BY `age`  DESC` I get Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 474 total, Query took 0.0557 sec) but guessing they are still repeated?

Comment: What is the datatype of m_dob?

Comment: No offense, but that stinks to high heaven.  Are you able to change it to date?

Comment: I know. I didnt create the db... I just dont wanna change it to date and then break something :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and your current query, you are not actually joining your tables. The two tables need to be joined on:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age  
FROM impressions AS i   
INNER JOIN mariners AS m  
  ON i.SessionId = m.ID
WHERE i.impression =1
  AND STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL 
  AND m_dob != '' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 BETWEEN 13 AND 50 
ORDER BY `age` DESC
```

Your current query is returning a [Cartesian result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of the dates.

Comment: Why when I run this joining Impression (and taking away the `i.impression =1` ) I get  474 total results but when I run the same query but when i take the impression join away i only get ( 28 total, Query took 0.0051 sec) from Mariners table?

Comment: @JonathanThurft I think you are going to have to post your table structure some sample data and then the desired result.  Without seeing these details it will be difficult, it sounds like you have a one-to-many relationship between the to tables that is causing the increase in rows.

Comment: Here is the tructure http://www.seafarersupport.org/dbstructure.pdf. The returning data is the AGE calculation that if taken only from mariners  table returns 28 results. and tehe impressions table has ID, Date, SessionID, Charity, Contacted, Type.

Comment: I've tried `SELECT DISTINCT(m.ID),  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age  FROM  mariners AS m INNER JOIN impressions AS i on i.SessionID = m.ID  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') IS NOT NULL AND m_dob != '' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(m.m_dob, '%d-%b-%Y'))), '%Y')+0 BETWEEN 13 AND 50 ORDER BY `age`  DESC` trying to get different results but still i get 19 in the new query vs 28

Comment: @JonathanThurft Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with the necessary columns from each table and some sample data?